# How to find a specific string in 1 or 2 sheets of a excel file using Apache POI?

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I need to find an specific string (id, name for example) in 1 sheet of excel.
this is a basic need.

Later on we need to find a user on several excel sheets and copy the whole record identified with that code and send it to a `JTable` in the frame.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for a high-level search function or something?  I don't think that exists.

As you load the sheets, you might consider just adding the interesting columns to a HashMap if you can use exact matches, otherwise just iterate over the sheets/columns/rows and search manually.

You could create some mid-level tooling to do this.  A "Sheet Indexer" perhaps, that takes a sheet and a list of columns then lets you do lookups.  Even if you have to write code to iterate over everything manually you shouldn't worry too much about speed--the number of sheets/rows are very unlikely to get large enough to effect performance or anything.

We actually have a lot of tooling built around poi including a ORM layer that lets us load from spreadsheets using annotations just like hibernate.  We called it "son of poi" aka "poison".